# Setting up CloudWatch dimensions for APIGateway methods in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an api say `apifortest` which has at 10 methods under different paths. Those methods are `GET`, `PUT` and `POST`. What I want to do is create a CloudWatch monitor for these.

I was looking at documentation here

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/api-gateway-metrics-dimensions.html

This is what I had earlier

```
TestApiCloudWatch:
    Type: "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm"
    Properties:
        ActionsEnabled: "True"
        AlarmName: "ApiGateway-TestAPI-5XXError-SEV2"
        ComparisonOperator: !FindInMap [APIGatewayCloudWatchMappings, 5XXError-SEV2, ComparisonOperator]
        Dimensions:
            -
                Name: "ApiName"
                Value: "APIForTest"
            -
                Name: "Stage"
                Value: "Prod"
        EvaluationPeriods: !FindInMap [APIGatewayCloudWatchMappings, 5XXError-SEV2, EvaluationPeriods]
        MetricName: !FindInMap [APIGatewayCloudWatchMappings, 5XXError-SEV2, MetricName]
        Namespace: "AWS/ApiGateway"
        Period: !FindInMap [APIGatewayCloudWatchMappings, 5XXError-SEV2, Period]
        Statistic: !FindInMap [APIGatewayCloudWatchMappings, 5XXError-SEV2, Statistic]
        Threshold: !FindInMap [APIGatewayCloudWatchMappings, 5XXError-SEV2, Threshold]
```

But this alarm is being set **At API Level**. I want to setup at method level. The documetion does states that we can do so, but it doesn't have any example.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation lists the dimensions you need to use:

- API Name - the name of the API. You already have this.
- Stage - the name of the stage of the API. You already have this.
- Method - The HTTP method (e.g. GET, PUT, DELETE)
- Resource - The resource path (e.g. /foo/bar)

Comment: This helps a lot @Bob Kinney, thanks! Is * supported for method and /* for Resource?

Comment: @KarthikVasishtaRamesh I don't believe so, no. You should be able to emulate this with CW metrics searches.